# SMB response, STATUS_INSUFF_SERVER_RESOURCES

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtual-machine, vmware, smb

I have a Windows 7 vm running in VMWare workstation, it has 4 cores and 4 GBs of RAM assigned.  Currently 3 clients connect to this windows 7 vm to access a shared folder. I noticed when the clients are in use, they throw random errors, referring to the share "system error 58..." "share cannot be accessed".  I captured some network traffic in wireshark and found the server VM in question is responding to SMB requests with Error: STATUS_INUFF_SERVER_RESOURCES.  Googling led me to [this](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/307257) article.

So far the problem seems to persist.  Can anyone give any advice?

EDIT:

On further inspection, the server is responding to SMB2 packets perfectly (win7 client) and throwing the insuff error on SMB queries (winXP) machine.